# What are the possible options to simv executable and what are their meaning?

Tags: version-control, verilog

What are possible arguments/options for the executable simv?

Indicating a reference document that I can download from the net would greatly help.

Answer (score 0):

The command line arguments for simv are available from [Solvnet](http://solvnet.synopsys.com). However you will need to have an account with Synopsys to get access to the document. The information is available as part of the VCS/VCSMX userguide.

I could not find a -h/--help equivalent option for the simv executable that shows all the available command line options.